# Centre of mass calculation returns this error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, pygame

Im trying to write a program that finds the centre of mass of a number of particles. It will be given the coordinates and masses of each particle. Except when it tries to add up the masses to find the total it returns the above error.
Here is my code.

```
def centre(masses, positions):
    total = 0
    xbar = 0
    ybar = 0
    for i in range(0, len(masses)-1):
        total += int(masses[i])

    for i in range(0, len(positions)-1):
        j, k = positions[i]
        xbar += (int(j)*int(masses[i]))
    if total != 0:
        x = xbar/total
        y = ybar/total
    else:
        x = 0
        y = 0
    return (x,y)
```

Comment: What are your inputs? Also post stack trace...

Comment: Has no bearing on the error, but you can return (0,0) as soon as you see that total is 0, after the first cycle. Also, you are not updating ybar, only xbar. As for the error, a very real possibility is that the two arrays have not the same size (or one contains a null string).

Comment: It would be good to include the invalid literal itself rather than cutting off the error message there.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 , he did not cut off the error. The literal is '' -- an empty string.

Comment: Ah ha! I thought maybe it was just an ending double-quote and he forgot the starting double-quote.

Comment: You should add the input for us to be sure what the problem is

Comment: @RafaelCardoso, I suspect that as soon as he inspects the input, the light will dawn. At least, that's the way it usually happens to me: I *never* see it until I tell someone else :-)

Comment: Here is what your code does: it assumes that masses is a sequence of objects that can be converted to integers by the int() function.  It assumes that positions is a sequence of two-element sequences, the first of which is convertible to an integer by the int function.  The second one is not used.  The variable ybar is never changed so it will always be zero.  The last element in both sequences (masses and positions) is ignored since i will never take the value len(masses)-1 - that's how the range function works,  When you compute x and y, do you mean to use / or //?  There's a difference.

Comment: You should post the traceback so we know which line you are on. It tells you that one of your inputs is an empty string and tells you exactly which line has the error. So, now you need to figure out why you got an empty string in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that one of the elements of masses is an empty string.  Find that and you get past this problem.